# Hierarchy of components and getting async data

Tags: reactjs, redux

First of all - sorry for my bad English, hope you get my meaning and you will be able to give me an answer.

So, I have the following project structure:

**App** (Root component) -> **Header** (included within App) -> **Navigation** (included within Header).

How should I send data to Navigation (which getting async..)

Now im getting that data in App. then via props send it to Header, and then - render it in Navigation.

1. I dont want to show Navigation component until the data is loaded.
2. I dont want Navigation to depend on Header....

**At the time - it looks like:**

*I cant put more then 2 links, that why I just leave here project.*

[Project (Github)](https://github.com/dontlemmedown/learn-redux)

Actually - it works! But you know, I dont sure that I've select the correct way..

Answer (score 0):

You can just get your component to return null

```
if (!this.props.data) {
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have ViewState stored in reducer to show loader or whatever until data loads or request fails; and you return false or null from render not to show up any markup if you need to.